# table inside a carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a newbie in web development. I'm have a table with more than 8 columns which also contain long text of data but its hard to display the data with such small screen. So I came up with this layout

[image]

The right two columns of the table is the major information ( Item ID and Description )and the left columns are the minor information ( quantity for example ). I want to minimize the table columns and just have a navigation for viewing the other information.

The problem is I don't know how would I do this and if it is possible?

Comment: loads of things are possible, even more so if you add the code you tried... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider collapsible elements like [accordions](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) within each table row. So only the major information is visible when the details are collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make the ID or Description into a hyperlink that links to another page that contains the minor data.  That would leave you with 1 table instead of 2. The challenge may be creating separate pages for each item's minor data, but there are ways of making that easier depending on what you are capable of/willing to try.